# creating a unique slug from name, check database existing slug

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slug

I am working on a web app at the moment, that takes a name from a user and generates a slug from it .e.g John Doe -> john-doe.

The slug needs to be unique as it is used an identifier, so I am I am currently doing the following,

`$slug = Str::slug($slug);

```
    //make sure it's unqiue
    $uniqueSlug = User::where('slug', $slug)->count();
    if($uniqueSlug > 0) {
        $slug .= "-" . $uniqueSlug;
    }
```

`

If a slug exists like john-doe, this would create john-doe-1, the problem is that the next john doe that comes along would also try to then make a unique john-doe-1 slug as the query is only looking for exact matches.

Is there a way that I can search the database for all occurances for john-doe + john-doe-

this way I know what number to append to the slug to make it unique

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users where slug like '% john-doe%'`?

Comment: You can append the user id.  That will ensure that it is unique.

Comment: https://laraveldaily.com/generate-slug-keyword-from-title-laravel-ajax/ check this.

Comment: There are already some nice solutions on GitHub for that. Search there for "laravel slug".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `composer require spatie/laravel-sluggable` package for generate unique slug

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Spatie\Sluggable\HasSlug;
use Spatie\Sluggable\SlugOptions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasSlug;

    /**
     * Get the options for generating the slug.
     */
    public function getSlugOptions() : SlugOptions
    {
        return SlugOptions::create()
            ->generateSlugsFrom('name')
            ->saveSlugsTo('slug');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is one of several available packages that will handle this for you (and my personal favorite; Spatie stuff is always well thought out and maintained).